# Apply jwt on express routes without raising an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

Is there a way to apply jwt on all my express routes with a middleware, but instead of raising an error if the token is missing or invalid, populate `req.user` with `null`

My current solution:

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var router = express.Router();

router.use(jwt({ secret: 'secret'}));

///////////////////////////////////////////
// This is the piece I would like to avoid
router.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err.code === 'UnauthorizedError') {
        req.user = null;
    }
    next();
})
///////////////////////////////////////////

router.use('/products', require('./products/products_router'));
```

In my route, i would like to have `req.user === null` if token was missing or invalid, and proper `req.user` if token was valid. Currently, without the piece of code I want to remove, my route is not executed without the token. And if I use `unless()`, the req.user is not populated even with a valid token

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? What you should be aiming to do is continue if good or throw errors where they're meant to be, not continue, else if your code relies on req.user being set, your unnecessarily need to handle it not being throughout your code..

Comment: Is it because you don't want it applied to every route?

Comment: Oh no sorry, I just meant I would prefer if there was a built-in flag or options I can set instead of custom code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt), you can specify the "credentialsRequired" property in the options object:

```
app.use(jwt({
  credentialsRequired: false
}));
```

You can see how this works here in the original source code:

```
if (!token) {
  if (credentialsRequired) {
    return next(new UnauthorizedError('credentials_required', { message: 'No authorization token was found' }));
  } else {
    return next();
  }
}
```